# Access callback for blocks

Tags: users, routes, blocks

We have "access callback" and "access argument" for defining the access to pages.

What is the way to restrict showing blocks? Can "access callback" also be defined in `hook_block_info()`, or through any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array returned from the implementations of `hook_block_info()` doesn't contain a property equivalent to the access callback for the menus. If you have a module that implements a block, then you can implement [hook_block_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) using code that checks if the user has a specific permission. The following code is used from a Drupal module; as you see the block is "rendered" only when the user has the "access content" permission.

```
case 'recent':
  if (user_access('access content')) {
    $block['subject'] = t('Recent content');
    if ($nodes = node_get_recent(variable_get('node_recent_block_count', 10))) {
      $block['content'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'node_recent_block', 
        '#nodes' => $nodes,
      );
    }
    else {
      $block['content'] = t('No content available.');
    }
  }
  break;
```

You can use similar code, but checking a different permission, even a custom one your module uses for checking if the user can see the block.

Answer (score 2):

You can also control access to other blocks by implementing [hook_block_list_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_list_alter/7), just remove the blocks which you don't want to be displayed on the current page from the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a PHP snippet in the block configuration, and check whether the current user has enough permissions to see the block.